# plugin not loading?

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have made another plugin with the same config file as another plugin which i developed, with the only difference being the name of the namespace and the module, which i have changed in all the places in all the files corresponding to the module.
can someone explain why it isnt working? because my previous plugin worked just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <ABC_Char>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </ABC_Char>
</modules>
   <default>
    <char_options><!-- tag of the system.xml section -->
        <section_one><!-- tag of the system.xml group -->
           <thank_note>
               Coupon wird eingelöst.</thank_note>
            <!-- tag of the system.xml field -->
        <!-- tag of the system.xml group -->
            <custom_field_one>Teile und spare</custom_field_one>
            <!-- tag of the system.xml field -->
        </section_one>
        <section_three><!-- tag of the system.xml group -->
            <top_margin>20</top_margin>
            <bottom_padding>10</bottom_padding>
            <!-- tag of the system.xml field -->
        </section_three>

    </char_options>
</default>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <push_order_to_thirdparty>
                    <class>ABC_Char_Model_Collectorobserver</class>
                    <method>pushDetails</method>
                </push_order_to_thirdparty>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>

        <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
            <observers>
                <addToCartButtonHandler>

                    <class>ABC_Char_Model_Addtocartobserver</class>
                    <method>applyCoupon</method>
                </addToCartButtonHandler>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
    </events>
    <layout>
    <updates>
        <mymodule>
            <file>char.xml</file> <!-- Our layout file name-->
        </mymodule>
    </updates>

    </layout>
    <routers>
        <char>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>ABC_Char</module>
                <frontName>char</frontName>
            </args>
        </char>
    </routers>


</frontend>


<global>

    <helpers>
        <abc_char>
            <class>ABC_Char_Helper</class>
        </abc_char>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <char>
            <class>ABC_Char_Model</class>
        </char>
    </models>
</global>


 <!--<default>
  <char_options>
    <section_one>

      <text_field>Default value</text_field>
    </section_one>
</char_options>
</default>-->
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <char_options>
                                        <title>Custom Configuration Section</title>
                                    </char_options>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

#### module xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
           <ABC_Char>
               <active>false</active>
               <codePool>community</codePool>
           </ABC_Char>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Comment: Have you got a module xml in etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml

Comment: yes with the propernaming convention too.

Comment: Please add the contents of the file inside `app/etc/modules` and also check your log files `var/logs/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log`. Have you got developer mode turned on also?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ABC_Char>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </ABC_Char>

    </modules>
</config>

Answer (score 0):

You need to set active to true in your etc/modules/Abc_Char.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ABC_Char>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </ABC_Char>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: ive already tried that.

Comment: After changing active to true did you also clear magento caches